# should i use lots of php/html files or just one?

Tags: php, html

I'm making a website for a friend and I have a general question about how I should make the files.

I've been making a seperate html file for each page (eg index.html, forgotpassword.html, activate.html etc.) and also a seperate PHP file for handling each form (eg processlogin.php, activate.php, forgotpassword.php etc)

I'm wondering if it is better practice to have one big php (or as few as possible) file to handle all the login/activate/forgot password etc forms. Should I also have one PHP file that echo's all the html files? Is there a way that is overwhelmingly better than another?

Comment: I think there isn't some "better" solution, for me I prefer to have my functions in 1 page instead of 1000 separated files, so I only have to include 1 file for my functions in my header.

Comment: @Marijke - that's why autoloaders are so useful, you don't need to worry about including everything manually

Comment: Using several differeent php files (depending on the scope of your project) is often easier to maintain. Additionally, this would allow for faster load times since you are only loading the php scripts you need to run each page, and not a massive php file when you are only loading the file for a few lines of the code.

Comment: I prefer separate files when necessary. Use require/include to connect them. Try MVC also.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Mark Baker, I'll take a quick look at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Is there a way that is overwhelmingly better than another?
```

There are many ways to handle this kind of "problem".

First, it's not better to have one big php file to handle the forms. Your approach to handle your HTML and PHP seperately is not too wrong altough you need to structure your application in a better way.

I would suggest you a front controller. That means: you have one file (index.php f.e) which takes all your requests and depending to the parameters send to it, it will handle the actions by including the appropriate files.

Also work with templates. Split your HTML up into several parts (header, content, footer)
so you don't have to include all of your HTML into every file. Instead of doing this you load your header and your footer (f.e) and depending on the parameters send to your front controller, you load the appropriate template file for your content.

Also take a look on the MVC approach for an even better seperation of concerns.

Comment: I took your advice and had a look at the MVC approach and, although it made my head hurt for a while, I've now implemented it and I think it will make my life much easier in the future :-)

Comment: Yeah for most of the people it can be very confusing understanding MVC when they've never heard of it before. But as you already said it's defenitely worth the effort :)

Answer (score 2):

The file separation must respond to these criteria :

1. Will it be easy to maintain and expend
2. Will I repeat my code often

That said, I suggest you to split at least like that :

1. General template (header.php, footer.php)
2. Page for typical content, informative page (including header.php + footer.php)
3. Page for each complex task example : contact form, login, forgot password, etc

One general practice is to include the login form inside the header.